# Need help method calling program - day number in year

Tags: java

basically I am in the middle of my program that involves asking a user to enter a day,month, and year, and based on that entry I am supposed to create a method that calculates the number of days in the year, but of course I need a method that defines how many days are in each month, and a method that determines whether or not it is a leap year or not. I have established my methods, user input, but now I am having method/return issue. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DayNumber{

public static void main(String[] args){
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the date's year (0001 - 9999): ");
  year = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter the date's month (1 - 12): ");
  month = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter the date's day (1 - 31): ");
  day = keyboard.nextInt();
}

public static int numberOfDays(int day, int month, int year){
  int numberOfDays;
  return numberOfDays;
}

public static int daysInMonth(int month, int year){
  int daysInMonth;

  if (month ==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 ||
        month==10 || month==12){

     month = 31;}

  if (month ==4 || month ==6 || month==9|| month==11){

     month = 30;}

  else if (month ==2){  

     if (){
     }
  }

  return daysInMonth;
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
  if (((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0)) || (year%400 ==0)){
     return true;
  }  
  else{
     return false;
  }
}

}
```

I would appreciate any advice or tips. I am really new to Java so go ahead and critique away! Thanks.

Comment: What "method/return issue" are you having?

Comment: I may be so new to Java I am not even sure how to format my question haha, but basically the issue that I am having is using the data I got from my boolean leap year method and plugging it into my days in month method if/else statement and from there calculating all of that in the number of days method.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways. Yours looks fine to me.

But my favorite is this tiny little line :

```
daysInMonth = (month === 2) ? (28 + isLeapYear) : 31 - (month - 1) % 7 % 2;
```

If you are asking yourself : Why % 7 % 2 ?

Well, you have noticed that starting from august, the pattern is reverted, that's what we are doing here. We say that between 0 - 6 it's normal then if it's 7 (7 % 7 = 0) we are going back from the beggining). Then the % 2 is to alternate between 0 - 1.

Hope I made myself clear

Comment: I think I am so lost that I didn't know how to ask the question haha. Basically, I am just struggling with taking my boolean value from my leapyear method and plugging it into my month method if/else statement for the value 2. And from there putting it all into my number of days method. I appreciate your advice though it makes sense but my question is not very clear at all

Comment: If I understand it right, this is what you want : 

    if ( isLeapYear(year) ){
        // Do stuff
     }

But I also see some errors here and there. (eg. month = 31) You probably mean daysInMonth. Also, you need to give daysInMonth a value at the beggining of the function otherwise your code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not clear. I tried to understand and here is my understanding:

1. Input date
2. Display number of days in month
3. Display whether year is leap year or not

Here is what I will do

```
Class MyDateHomework {
  public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) { 
    //put logic to find leapyear
  }
  public static int daysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    if(month == 2) {
      return isLeapYear(year) ? 28 : 29;
    }
    //put logic to find days in month
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //take input and call method to do homework
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, that makes more sense. I guess that I am so lost I don't even know how to ask my question haha. I think my main problem lies in my return statement in my boolean leapyear method. I am not sure how to tell my month method whether or not it is a leap year